# Realizing D_8 as a Galois group over C(x) with prescribed decomposition groups

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-curves, ag.algebraic-geometry

Coming up with examples of $D_8$-covers of $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is easy. For example:

$Quot(\mathbb{C}(x)[y,z]/(y^2=x(x-7), z^4=(y+\sqrt{-6})^2(y-\sqrt{-6})^2(y+\sqrt{-10})(-y+\sqrt{-10})^3))$

defines a $D_8$ extension of $\mathbb{C}(x)$. If you view this field extension as an extension of the corresponding smooth projective models, it is branched at $x=0,1,2,7$.

I wish to control the inertia groups (=decomposition groups, in this case) associated to the ramification.

I'll use the presentation $D_8= \langle a,b | a^4, b^2, ab=ba^{-1} \rangle$.

Take $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \setminus 0,7,1,2$. Its fundamental group is $\langle \gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3, \gamma_4| \gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3\gamma_4=1 \rangle$ (where $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3, \gamma_4)$ are respectively the loops from a fixed base point around the points $(0,7,1,2)$). The surjection: $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3, \gamma_4)$ goes to $(b, ab, a^2, a^3)$, gives a $D_8$-Galois cover of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$.

I wish to find the equations that define THAT $D_8$ cover. The equations I wrote in the beginning won't work because there the inertia groups of the ramification points above $x=0$ and above $x=7$ are the same groups; whereas if done through the description, since no conjugate of $b$ is equal to any conjugate of $ab$, no inertia group of any ramification point above $x=0$ will equal the inertia group of any ramification point above $x=7$.

For some reason I easily confuse myself in such computations.

If you mod out the description by $\langle a \rangle$ you see that the description of the $D_8 / \langle a \rangle$ sub-cover of the original cover, has description $(b\langle a \rangle, b\langle a \rangle, \langle a \rangle, \langle a \rangle)$, and therefore must be given by $y^2=x(x-7)$ (if it's, say, $y'^2=\frac{x}{x-7}$, then $y'=\frac{y}{x-7}$). But I can't find the right other equation that would make this work.

Note that this should be easy, because this $D_8/\langle a \rangle$-cover is a $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ with parameter $y$, so there's no funny business. And yet I'm having some trouble finishing this example up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, the fixed field by $\langle a\rangle$ is $\mathbb{C}(u)$ with $u^2=-5x/2(x-7)$, and the fixed field by $\langle a^2,b \rangle$ is similarly $\mathbb{C}(v)$ with $v^2=7(x-2)/2(x-7)$ (constants chosen so that $u^2+v^2=1$). So their compositum, the fixed field by $\langle a^2\rangle$, has genus zero and is $\mathbb{C}(t)$, where $u=2t/(t^2+1)$, $v=(t^2-1)/(t^2+1)$. This means that the last quadratic step of your tower is determined entirely by its ramification points, which are the 2 points above $x=2$ (which are the points $t=\pm 1$) and the 4 points above $x=1$, call them $t=c_1,\dots,c_4$. So your desired field is $\mathbb{C}(t,w)$ where $w^2=(t-c_1)(t-c_2)(t-c_3)/(t-c_4)(t^2-1)$.

Comment: I can summarize now what I neglected to notice. Every time I reached a genus 0 curve I should have found the parameter and worked with it instead (like you implicitly did). Great. The next examples will be much easier to do on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I need to do something explicit involving a Galois extension of a field whose Galois group is a small 2-group (and it does happen sometimes!) I always find what I need in the paper "Groups of order 16 as Galois groups," by Grundman, Smith, and Swallow.